# Spring error page without redirect

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement an error page that is shown if something goes wrong but without triggering a redirect.

As far as i understand it a `InternalResourceViewResolver` should do the trick.
i call "myurl" and this causes an error. the controller triggers my "error"-View and the view is shown instead of the normal response but the url of the resource is still "myurl".

Unfortunately this does not work. my config:

```
<bean id="cnManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="false" />
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="cnManager" />

    <!-- Define the view resolvers explicitly -->
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/errors/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

if i try to trigger my 500.html page in web-inf i only get a 404 response and the message that `/WEB-INF/errors/500.html` could not be found. additionally the log shows that there was a http request to exactly this url.

does anybody have any suggestion on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/error/uncaughtException.jsp</location>
  </error-page>  use full path in web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry in your web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errorpage.htm?error=500</location>
</error-page>
```

then make a controller

```
     @Controller
     public class ErrorPageController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/errorpage.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String Logout(ModelMap model, @RequestParam int error) {
     if(error==500)
    model.addAttribute("msg", "Please Give The Correct Input");

    return "errorpage";
}
```

then make a errorpage.jsp insinde your WEB-INF/error

Comment: this is pretty much what i did and it does not work. i only get a 404 page with the message that my web-inf/errors/500.jsp can not be found. i only get it to work if i resolve the view to an uri that actually exists.