# Issue with spring error-page and web.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

here is my web.xml:

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404</location>
</error-page>
```

Below is my Controller class :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


@RequestMapping(value = "/error")
@Controller
public class ErrorController {

@RequestMapping(value = {"/307", "/400", "/401", "/403", "/404", "/405", "500", "503"})
public ModelAndView error(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    String path = request.getServletPath().replace("/error/", "");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/error/view/"+path);
}
```

if I request error url like this

```
http://localhost:8080/erro/
```

it display 404 error-page but it change url

```
http://localhost:8080/error/view/404
```

If invalid URL is requested, the error page appears but old url has changed. What do I need to fix so that old url does not change and only the error page appears?

thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring error page without redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096572/spring-error-page-without-redirect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to use `forward:` instead of `redirect:`

[Redirect](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) is working on client side by sending `Location` header to the browser, that's why URL is changing.

[Forward](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-forward-prefix) is working on the server side by choosing the file that will be send as a response to the browser.

But **be very careful with forward**, because it could lead to a security issue if you will use it with user-controlled input. In that case attacker will be able [to download any file from your WAR](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet#Dangerous_Forward_Example) (it depends on your configuration but in some extremely cases he will be able to download even compiled java classes).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "redirect:". This will avoid the redirect and the url will not change.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/307", "/400", "/401", "/403", "/404", "/405", "500", "503"})
public ModelAndView error(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
   String path = request.getServletPath().replace("/error/", "");
   return new ModelAndView("/error/view/"+path);
```

}